# DSE search - Solr multi valued field schema can't be mapped with CAS schema :(

Tags: solr, cassandra, multivalue, datastax-enterprise

1. I start my DSE node as Solr node i.e. /dse cassandra -s
2. I then create KS and CF. My CF has KEY field only.
3. I then publish Solr schema and solr config on it. My Solr schema has dynamic field which is indexed and multivalued.
4. I then try to insert data into CAS on cql command prompt, something like below:-

insert into device (KEY, deviceid, qualifier0) VALUES (000000000000, '000000000000', ['v0', 'v1']);

it throw error, says - Invalid character '['.

Questions -

1. Are multivalue fields supported in DSE?
2. If yes then how can I use them?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the data type for qualifier0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to used advanced Solr features, you really should be inserting the data using the Solr HTTP API, not CQL.  But, I think you can insert into the multi valued field like so:

```
insert into device (KEY, deviceid, qualifier0) VALUES (000000000000, '000000000000', 'solrjson:[\'v0\',\'v1\']');
```